# Android app Activities

Tags: java, android, eclipse

how to use a separate class(`Activity`) to make a service or task at background without showing a layout?
i.e. if I want to make my code hidden as separating my code operations from the `MainActivity.class` and make it in separate class, how to use the separated java class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `setContentView()` method in ur activity `onCrate()`, that u want to hide.

Use [AsyncTask()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class to perform background operations.

Comment: I think he is interested in starting a service. So there is no point in creating another activity. Launching a unbound service is sufficient enough. Or to do away with the hassles of maintaining service life cycle, the OP can use IntentService. Just my 2 cents....

Comment: you both got my idea, I'm searching for keywords **AsyncTask()** and **unbound service** coz I'm a beginner. the deal is my manager want the app  `MainActivity` class to be clear from any hard code, and make my code in a separate java class

Comment: use Listener pattern. And plase all code to any class, that is non activity probably. U should know that by default activities run in one main thead.

Comment: but i really don't understand why u cant place code in MainActivity. U also can create the instance of any java class and use any public method in it.

Answer (score 0):

-You can create a new class `Myservice extends Service{  ..Your code...}`And use this service in your desired place THanks:)